# ngFor not updating when item removed

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm using *ngFor inside a page template (Ionic 2).

```
<div class="child" *ngFor="let child of sharedParams.children">
        ...
</div>
```

Somewhere inside the app, I update the children array when changes are detected (add, update, remove). I do this be assigning a new array to the property:

```
export class SharedParams {    
    private _children: Child[];

    constructor(children: Child[]){
        this._children = children;
    }

    get children(){
        return this._children;
    }

    set children(children: Child[]){        
        this._children = children;
    }
}
```

When an item is added or updated inside the array, the ngFor is triggered and the DOM is updated. However, when an item is removed, the array is changed, but the DOM does not remove the entry for that item.

I've also tried to manually modify the array instead of replacing it, using 'push' and 'splice'. But the behaviour stays the name. The DOM is never updated when an item is removed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What kind of values does `sharedParams.children` contain? Normally replacing should work in any case. Can you provide a Plunker to reproduce?

Comment: sharedParams.children is an array of type Child (Child[]). This is a custom class containing some primitive properties (mostly strings).

Comment: Never heard of such an issue. I suspect a problem with your code. A Plunker would be required to investigate.

Comment: What ionic version are you using? ( ionic --v ). I had a similar problem in beta.23 that was resolved in beta.25

Comment: Sadly I'm already using beta.25 :(

Comment: try slicing the item out of the children array using its index value

Comment: Yes, already did that. No luck... I've rewritten the system to create a new local array, which is then modify using "push" and "slice". Adding items works without a problem. Slicing however not. The length of the array does change, but when I output the length using {{children.length}}, it does not change when removing an item. Again, it does when adding an item.

Comment: I have no ides if this works or not, but try to change the datatype from ``Child[]`` to ``Array<Child>``

Comment: What about `let child of sharedParams._children` (with an underscore)?

Comment: I have the same same problem. tried the same things as you C.Sysmans Addition or updating works, removal does not

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I'm facing the same issue with 2.0.0-rc.4.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#changedetectorref) to check and update the list every 0.5 seconds or more...

For example:

```
constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    console.log('Hello PhotoComponent Component');  
    setInterval(() => {
      this.ref.detectChanges();
    }, 500);  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case [`ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html#!#detectChanges-anchor) did the trick. The problem seems to appear when you update the model from an Observable, for example the response of a Http.get().

Using `NgZone.run()` didn't help, I tried that before.