# Disable multiple selection in checkbox

Tags: html, ionic-framework, checkbox, ionic3

This is my code :

```
<ion-list class="ion-list">
            <ion-item *ngFor="let item of ProductType; let i= index" class="item-checkbox ion-list-item">
                <ion-label class="checkbox">{{item.name}}</ion-label>
                <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="item.isChecked" multiple="false"></ion-checkbox>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
```

In above code user can select more than 1 check box..But i want to allow user to select only one check box.How can i achieve this.

Please help me out.Thanks in advance !!

Uodated :

```
this.ProductType = [{ name: "sec", isChecked: false },
    { name: "min", isChecked: false }
    ];
```

Comment: Use radio instead of checkbox.

Comment: my requirement is have to use checkbox, thats why i was not able to achieve

Comment: well then you will need to have a piece of javascript to handle that. are you allowed to use that?

Comment: yes, that i can do, but now idea how to achive that ..but i am usng ionic v3, ts file

Comment: @wayneOS  Any idea ?

Answer (score -1):

I created a single function for you hope it helps:

```
   <ion-list class="ion-list">
            <ion-item *ngFor="let item of ProductType; let i= index" class="item-checkbox ion-list-item">
                <ion-label class="checkbox">{{item.name}}</ion-label>
                <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="item.isChecked" multiple="false" (change)="checkboxToRadio(i)"></ion-checkbox>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>



 checkboxToRadio(index) {
    let tempArr = [];
    this.ProductType.map((item, i) => {
      console.log(this.ProductType[i])
      tempArr[i] = item;
      console.log(i +"fdsa"+index);
      if (i == index) {
        // tempArr[i].isChecked = !item.isChecked; 
      } else {
        tempArr[i].isChecked = false;
      }
    });
    this.ref.detectChanges();
    this.ref.markForCheck();
    this.ProductType = tempArr;
  }
```

I think your ngFor is not updating please check this answer of look to fix it
Here is a similar problem to yours
[ngFor not updating when item removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37437347/ngfor-not-updating-when-item-removed)

Here is the working demo of what you need
[Stackblitz demo](https://checkbox-use-as-radio-ionic.stackblitz.io)

Comment: Thanks, checking it

Comment: still same..i selecting more than 1 checkbox

Comment: any alternative solution please

Comment: still same...its selecting more than 1 checkbox

Comment: I  think your ngFor is not updating please check this answer of look to fix it Here is a similar problem to yours https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37437347/ngfor-not-updating-when-item-removed

Comment: please check my updated post.i have added the structure how i am adding the `ProductType`

Comment: Hey I've added a working demo and edited my answer.Please accept this answer if it helped

Comment: i have updated ur code, but its same issues only i am getting ..how ur demo is working fine ??..i am also using same code ...`ngFor not updating when item removed` this alos i needs to fix

Comment: Have you checked out my demo

Comment: yes, but why mine is not working..thats only i am confused

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/checkbox-use-as-radio-ionic here is the link you can check and edit it from here